# Xml drawable is pixelated when enlarged

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I am using this image:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="32dp"
android:height="39dp"
android:viewportWidth="32"
android:viewportHeight="39">
<path
  android:pathData="M15.8575,6.5831L15.8575,1.0031C15.8575,0.1031 14.7775,-0.3369 14.1575,0.3031L6.5575,7.8831C6.1575,8.2831 6.1575,8.9031 6.5575,9.3031L14.1375,16.8831C14.7775,17.5031 15.8575,17.0631 15.8575,16.1631L15.8575,10.5831C23.3175,10.5831 29.2175,17.4231 27.5775,25.1631C26.6375,29.7031 22.9575,33.3631 18.4375,34.3031C11.2975,35.8031 4.9375,30.9031 3.9775,24.2831C3.8375,23.3231 2.9975,22.5831 2.0175,22.5831C0.8175,22.5831 -0.1425,23.6431 0.0175,24.8431C1.2575,33.6231 9.6175,40.1231 19.0775,38.2831C25.3175,37.0631 30.3375,32.0431 31.5575,25.8031C33.5375,15.5431 25.7375,6.5831 15.8575,6.5831Z"
  android:strokeWidth="1"
  android:fillColor="#fff"
  android:fillType="evenOdd"
  android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
 <path
  android:pathData="M-34,-30h100v100h-100z"
  android:strokeWidth="1"
  android:fillType="evenOdd"
  android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
</vector>
```

as `drawableStart` in a button

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_restart"
```

I am using focus navigation, so in `onFocusChanged` of the button I am enlarging it with this extension:

```
fun View.enlarge(turnOn: Boolean) {
   if (turnOn) {
       translationZ = 1f
       scaleX = 1.2f
       scaleY = 1.2f
   } else {
       translationZ = 0f
       scaleX = 1.0f
       scaleY = 1.0f
   }
}
```

It works very well, however the drawable is pixelated after I enlarge it even though it is xml. The image loses its quality. What is causing this and how can I avoid it and keed the image looking good?

EDIT: tried different approach according to answer below, but was not successful

```
override fun onFocusChanged(gainFocus: Boolean, direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?) {
  if (gainFocus) {
    imageView.layoutParams.height = 60
    imageView.layoutParams.width = 60
  } else {
    imageView.layoutParams.height = 50
    imageView.layoutParams.width = 50
  }
}
```

or

```
override fun onFocusChanged(gainFocus: Boolean, direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?) {
  if (gainFocus) {
    imageView.drawable.setBounds(0,0,60,60)
  } else {
    imageView.drawable.setBounds(0,0,50,50)
  }
}
```

None of these two methods are working. This time the icon is pixelated when made smaller.

What is still wrong with VectorDrawable?

Answer (score 1):

Using Scale X/Y to enlarge your views make them lose quality, instead increase the width and height, since you're using a vector drawable it would scale properly with it, to do this in code, use the layout param of the view... but note that the drawable of a button does not scale with the button so you should try something else like an image button or a linear layout with the drawable beside the button.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. Trying to do enlarge via drawable.setBounds() or imageview.layoutParams, but none of them is working. Image is still pixelated, but this time it is pixelated when it is returned to smaller state. Updated question.